# When does Zabbix display graph lines connected?

Tags: graph, monitoring, zabbix

When Zabbix graphs show items with missing values, the graph line is shown interrupted:

[image: Line interruped]

In my eyes this shall show visually that there aren't any values between 5:25 and 5:55. This seems completely correct.

But I have another graph where the line between the values before and after the gap are displayed connected:

[image: Line connected]

Both graphs are using different items (but in this case the same or similiar values). Both items don't have values from about 5:25 to 5:55. Both graphs are equally configured - as far as I can see...

**What is the difference? Why is the second line displayed connected?**

I also tried different draw styles (Line, filled region etc.) as described in Zabbix docu [Custom graphs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/visualisation/graphs/custom) - always the same. Zabbix seems to have some other criteria to decide if the graph should be shown connected or interrupted.

Comment: Very similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/127850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on item type, item interval configuration and the graph width.

- item type - for trapper items, a line will always be drawn from one value to the next, and a straight line to the graph edge
- item interval configuration and graph width - depending on how frequently the values are collected, how many are missing and how long the gap would be pixel-wise

Note that I said "item interval configuration" - flexible intervals and item scheduling can affect this in other, sometimes quite obscure, ways.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer: Indeed, in my case, the first (interrupted) graph shows a (dependent) item with update interval of 5m, the second (connected) graph shows a trapper item. Nevertheless, the answer is not very satisfactory - which is not you fault...Is this behaviour documented anywhere to explain the reasons? (In my eyes the first line also should be displayed interrupted - but ok, Zabbix doesn't know if there are any missing items because is doesn't know the currect interval in case of a trapper item. But I would like to be able to configure this...)

Comment: I recall it being documented, but cannot find the location right now. If you'd like to see it changed, vote on https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-3356 .